# 2sxc Staging and Live editions not rendering

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I am using 2sxc(10.x) template-angular8 with DNN (9.4x) and it works as is desired with the local edition.
Then I publish to staging and live editions, when I select either the live or staging, nothing is rendered on the page.

I have been careful to follow the instructions on https://azing.org/2sxc/r/BgOY2BmS

I believe I am missing something and would appreciate if you can point it out to me.

I have included the folder structure and screen shots to hopefully help you understand my issue.
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LbV5.jpg)[Local Edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEYZH.jpg)[Staging Edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ObMR.jpg)

Comment: Can you destribe how you "publish" to staging and live environments?

Comment: Thanks Joe, first, on the command line, I navigate to the root of the folder from where I would normally type: npm run local. This time, I type: npm run build-to-staging, and after that, npm run build-to-live. Please let me know if this is not clear.